# "Contract" jobs confusion

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

What exactly is a "contract" job? When I hear that I picture a part time project (or maybe a few projects) that is paid hourly or a fixed amount. Possibly with the potential to convert to full time.

I have a full time job that I'm very happy with but I'm looking for some side work. But when I filter for "contract" work I see these 43 results.

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=laravel&type=contract&allowsremote=true

Many of which have a **salary** listed, which conflicts with my understanding of contract work.

Are employers just checking the "contract" checkbox to get more eyes on their listings? Or do I have a misunderstanding of the term? If it's the latter, would it be possible for us to filter by part time / single project jobs?

Comment: Hm,'lots of the listings are advertising benefits like health insurance, life insurance, vacation, and retirement plans. Actual (IRS permitted) 1099 contractors **do not get** those things. One even says "**Please no staffing agencies or contractors**". Something isn't right.

Comment: In Europe you will find many IT type jobs are contract work. You are salaried but you are hired in for a specific contract term. At the end of that term you might be offered to continue or not. In a sense it creates a situation where you need to continue to perform or you won't be renewed. Thus avoids all if the discomfort if firing.

Answer (score 6):

It's a common thing in Europe, and particularly in the UK.  Many IT workers own their own company and do work on a fixed rate, fixed term basis through that company.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to to clear this up as best as I understand the situation in the "real world":

1. The job could be listed by a *contractor* that is looking to hire *full time workers* to then contract out to a client. The client's details are probably what you see on the page; the benefits are from the *contractor* that employs you; and the fact that its a contract job means you are - for legal and practical purposes - not a hired employee of the contracting client.
2. The other kind of contract job is a non-employee, non-salaried work based on a specific project or time frame. I am not sure if the system allows the posters to be more granular in how they write the salaries. These are the jobs where you'll generally see "no staffing agencies or contractors" - in this case *contractors* means *"companies that sign contracts to supply manpower"*; and not the individual person.

Answer (score 5):

Contractor in general is a loosely used term nowadays, at least in the U.S.. I did `contract` work for the military for 6 years, but was a W2 employee for the company that held that specific contract with the military. In those situations your employment is dependent upon that company holding the contract for its entirety, and when renewed. Which is why my resume will show I "technically" changed jobs multiple times, because a company does not always get renewed as someone else outbids it.

In general on job postings (applies to Indeed, CareerBuilder, etc. also) recruiters are posting the job as both "permanent" and "contractor" to get more eyes on the posting...plain and simple. To differentiate between what is really a contract job is going to be difficult and up to SE on how they implement it. All job posting sites have the issue that recruiters will mis-use the system. Even if you add the ability to break down a job category to part-time they could likely still flag the job as that to just get eyes on it.

In your reference to side work or single project jobs I consider that freelance work. Which might not be a bad idea if SE was up to opening it up to those type of postings. Freelance sites like freelance.com or guru.com are common places to find freelance jobs but it is a bidding system, where you bid on what work you could do. I can't stand those sites or that format. I can tell you the DBA work I used to do on the side for almost 3 years, I got from strict word-of-mouth. You are not likely going to find much of that type of job posting on any job site I have come across.

Comment: I agree, I hate the bidding model. I bet SE could implement something similar to the Q&A portion of the site. People like me could flag postings if they're in the wrong category, and if the company that posted it gets 4 strikes then they're out. The good companies that respect the rules won't have any problem, the bad ones need SE more than SE needs them. All easier said than done, I know.

Comment: @andrewtweber Would you make a feature request out of that?

Comment: Here in the UK a lot of people have their own companies working full time for their clients, other IT companies. A contractor typically work for a short period of time, earn more money and doesn't have social benefit like holidays. The difference is crystal clear. You can choose to have a steady job and work years for same boss or being a contractor, relocate frequently for work and decide whether or not to extend with same client.

Comment: What you described sounds like subcontracting. Being a subcontractor means being an individual or in many cases a business that signs a contract to perform part or all of the obligations of another's contract.

Answer (score -3):

Contract work means that you sign a contract to work for a company at a fixed rate for a fixed period of time based on the details of the contract. You will not get company benefits like healthcare, disability insurance, IRA matching, etc. In the United States, you will have to pay an additional 8% as self-employment tax on top of the normal 8% for social security and Medicare. Think of contract work as you running your own business and offering your services to a company. The only benefit is that you can deduct any purchases you make that could be construed as a business expense. See tax laws for details but this can work to your advantage.

As a full-time employee, you gain various legal, tax, and company benefits as a result of your employment. You would be entitled to health care insurance, dental, etc. and whatever else the company offers. Benefits can equate to 20-25% of your annual salary in addition to your salary so nothing to sneeze at. For tax purposes, in the USA, for instance, you would pay 8% social security and Medicare tax while the company pays the other 8%. This is better than the 16% self-employment tax you would otherwise pay as a contractor.

Depending on where you live, there are also legal advantages to being an employee. For instance, in my state, you can't get fired for discrimination or retaliation but these laws wouldn't apply to a contract position.

Contractors are easier for companies to get rid of but you can sometimes make more on contract than you could as an employee. All depends on the situation and the circumstances. However, if you are getting paid the same amount on contract as you would as an employee, being an employee is better because of the company benefits, tax advantages, and legal protections you gain.